# Why is the size of image file different on google pagespeed from file on disk?

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I did a google padespeed insights test and it showed my images are 350.6 KiB but when I check the file on my desktop it shows it's only 90kb.

Why is there a difference in the size of the same file on website and on disk?

Comment: A difference in size you call that? Four times as big!

Comment: Do you have any image optimisation plugins? Or CDN? Maybe it's not firing for lab tests?

Comment: Check the file size on FTP